# Ratio of two infinite series of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have functions $f,g:\mathbb{N}\times [0,1]\to [0,1]$ such that $0\leq f(n,x),g(n,x)\leq 1$ and
$$\frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n,x)}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty g(n,x)}<\infty$$
for every $x\in[0,1]$. Is there anything that we can say about the individual series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n,x)$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty g(n,x)$? I was hoping one may be able to say something about the convergence/divergence of these series under the assumption that their ratio is finite however it has not yet come clear to me. Clearly, if the individual series are finite then so too is their ratio but does this necessarily go the other way?

Comment: Do you mean $$\frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n,x)}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty g(n,x)}<\infty$$ or $$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sum_{n=0}^N f(n,x)}{\sum_{n=0}^N g(n,x)}<\infty$$
Both are different statements. The first one obviously implies that both series converge, otherwise this expression won't even be a number, and the seconde one implies nothing (for example, we have have $f=g$ and this ratio will always be one).

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Let $A(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n,x)$ and $B(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty g(n,x),$ both $\in[0,+\infty].$ What does your "$\frac {A(x)}{B(x)}<\infty$" mean? Moreover, what is the point of making all this depend on a real variable $x?$

Comment: Did you think of the case $f=g$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{n=0}^Nf(n,x)}{\sum\limits_{n=0}^Ng(n,x)}=L\in\mathbb R_+$$
$L\ge0$ because $f$ and $g$ are non-negative. Let's denote $S_N=\sum\limits_{n=0}^Nf(n,x)$ and $R_N=\sum\limits_{n=0}^Ng(n,x)$. So we have
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{S_N}{R_N}=L$$
If $L\ne0$ then $S_N$ converges if and only if $R_N$ converges.

Let's now analyse the case $L=0$. Convergence of $S_N$ doesn't imply anything, $R_N$ could converge ($f(n,x)=1/n^2$ and $g(n,x)=1/n$) or diverge ($f(n,x)=1/2^n$ and $g(n,x)=1/n^2$). But if $R_N$ is bounded (hence convergent, because it is non-decreasing), we have $n_0$ such that for $n\ge n_0$
$$\frac{S_N}{R_N}<\frac{1}{2}\Rightarrow S_N\le\frac{1}{2}R_N$$
then $S_N$ will be also bounded, thus convergent.

Comment: Also sorry for poor english, not my first language